# An elementary exercise from modules over algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I was trying to prove following equivalence of statements: let $V$ be an $A$-module, $A$ is an algebra of finite dimension over a field $F$. Then following are equivalent:

1) $V$ is completely reducible $A$-module (i.e. it is direct sum of simple $A$-submodules).

2) $J(A)V=0$, where $J(A)$ is Jacobson radical of $A$.

I didn't get any direction to proceed; any **hint**?

Comment: In (1) do you mean $V$ is semisimple? Any module is the direct sum of itself...

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was my mistake.

Comment: Are you missing an extra condition on $V$, like it being artinian or something? I can see (1) implies (2), but the converse (at least whenever I have seen it before) requires $V$ to be atleast artinian. Although I'll admit this isn't exactly my strongest area.

Comment: I have not seen such conditions; (see https://books.google.co.in/books?id=lyqAvBzeBSAC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false, first problem on page 15)

Comment: Wouldn't $V=\prod_{i\in \mathbb{R}}S$ where $S$ is a simple $A$-module be a counterexample since $J(A)\cdot V =0$ but $V$ is not completely reducible.

Comment: On page 5 he says: "we will assume every $A$-module has finite dimension over F".

Comment: OK; was not too aware of it; thanks for pointing it. Any hint then to proceed for equivalence?\

Comment: Well for the first direction, think about how the Jacobson acts on simple modules. For the converse direction, the important point is that the finite dimension implies finite maximal submodules. So then perhaps you could use something like a chinese remainder theorem?.

Comment: Jacobson radical acts trivially on any *simple* $A$-module, so it acts trivially on any $A$-module, is this right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49830/discussion-between-leon-sot-and-p-groups).

Comment: Are those not all the same submodule? After all, $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & a \end{smallmatrix}\right)\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 0 \\ \lambda & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right) = \left(\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 0 \\ a\lambda & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$. Finite dimensionality implies the module is artinian, and this implies only finite maximal submodules by considering the descending sequence of intersections, eventually one maximal submodule must lie in the intersection of the others. Although I'm not the best at this, so I might be wrong.

Comment: Actually, I retract my above statement. I was confusing the argument used for rings. Finite dimensional modules can have infinite maximal submodules. The actual property that I was hinting at above was that the radical $rad(M)$ is the intersection of a finite number of maximal modules if the module is artinian. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @LeonSot You were right about my example. I think the example still exists, I'm just misremembering.

Comment: @LeonSot Ah, now I remember. This was an example of infinitely many maximal *right* ideals. Of course, to make it an infinte family of maximal left ideals, we just take the transpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $J(R)$ annihilates $V$, then $V$ is also an $R/J(R)$ module.

Since $R/J(R)$ is Artinian, it is a semisimple ring, so $V$ is a semisimple $R/J(R)$ module. But $R$ and $R/J(R)$ share the same simple modules, so $V$ is also a semisimple $R$ module.

For the other direction, I think you've already seen that $J(R)$, which annihilates all simple $R$ modules, obviously annihilates all semisimple $R$ modules.